# Cannot assign value to datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, html, datetimepicker

I want to assign value to datetimepicker, but isn't work anymore.

I tried, but the results were not as expected.

Jquery to assign value :

```
$('#iTTDateOpen').data('datetimepicker').setLocalDate(new Date(2019, 6, 2, 10, 55));
```

HTML Code :

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label">TT Date Open</label>
<div class="col-md-7">
<input type="text" id="iTTDateOpen" class="form-control txt filter-time" placeholder="Trouble Ticket Date Open" onkeydown="return false" required>
</div>
</div>
```

I expected the output is `2019-06-02 10:55`, but the actual output is `/Date(1559001300000)/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved.

On your database, convert the value using varchar :

`convert(VARCHAR, trx.TroubleTicketDateOpen,20)`

On your HTML, add properties like :

`<input type="text" id="iTTDateOpen" class="form-control txt filter-time" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss" placeholder="Trouble Ticket Date Open" onkeydown="return false" required>`

On your JavaScript :

`$('#iTTDateOpen').val(dt.TroubleTicketDateOpen);`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
$('#iTTDateOpen').html(new Date(2019, 6, 2, 10, 55));
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but still not work for me.